# Tool to enforce python code style/standards

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm trying to find a tool to check for coding style in python.

For PHP I've seen there is the Code Sniffer, and a small [perl script](http://drupal.org/coding-standards#helper) used by Drupal. Is there such a tool for python code?

Comment: I've just found about pep8.py, but the page doesn't load. However it's still in the Google cache http://74.125.93.132/search?q=cache:-sI5YpbDc9MJ:svn.browsershots.org/trunk/devtools/pep8/pep8.py+pep8.py

Is it the only tool? are there any other better?

Comment: It's 2018! These days you might want to take a look at [Black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the past I've mainly use [PyLint](http://www.logilab.org/857) - it can highlight when you used an undefined variable, when you import things without using them and so on.

It can be a bit verbose, complaining about things like lines being over 80 character long, variable not matching to specific regex's, classes having too few public methods, methods missing docs-trings.

For example, for script..

```
import os
import somefakelib

def myfunc(x):
    blah = "Something"
    print os.listdir( x+blh )
```

PyLint generates the following messages:

```
C:  1: Missing docstring
F:  2: Unable to import 'somefakelib' (No module named somefakelib)
C:  4:myfunc: Missing docstring
C:  4:myfunc: Invalid name "x" (should match [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$)
C:  4:myfunc: Invalid name "x" (should match [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$)
E:  6:myfunc: Undefined variable 'blh'
W:  5:myfunc: Unused variable 'blah'
W:  2: Unused import somefakelib
```

They are all valid complaints, but I tend to disable a lot of the convention and refactoring messages. You can disable specific messages, either as comments in your code:

```
#pylint:disable-msg=R0903,C0103,R0903,F0401,C0301
```

..or as command line arguments to the PyLint command:

```
pylint --disable-msg=R0903,C0103,R0903,F0401,C0301 myfile.py
```

With the above messages disabled, it generates the following messages for the above code:

```
C:  1: Missing docstring
C:  4:myfunc: Missing docstring
E:  6:myfunc: Undefined variable 'blh'
W:  5:myfunc: Unused variable 'blah'
W:  2: Unused import somefakelib
```

PyLint also generates a "code report", including how many lines of code/comments/docstring/whitespace the file has, number of messages per-category, and gives your code a "score" - 10 being no messages, 0 generally being a syntax error

Another option is [PyFlakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes), which I find a little less excessively-verbose (I've recently started using it in place of PyLint). Again using the above script, PyFlakes gives the following messages:

```
example.py:2: 'somefakelib' imported but unused
example.py:6: undefined name 'blh'
```

The final option I use is `pep8.py`, which as the name suggests enforces [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is by far the most.. pedantic script, enforcing things like correct blank-lines before/after functions/classes, spacing around code, correct 4-space indentation and so on..

Running on the code above, it produces the following:

```
example.py:4:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
example.py:6:23: E201 whitespace after '('
example.py:6:32: W292 no newline at end of file
```

It is mostly enforces stylistic things like correct whitespace, it does not do much static-analysis of the code like PyLint or PyFlakes, so I use pep8.py in conjunction with either PyLint or PyFlakes.

`pep8.py` was originally announced on the [python mailing list here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2006-December/005491.html), but the download link in this is now dead.. There's a github mirror by cburroughs, with a few minor fixes at [github.com/cburroughs/pep8.py](http://github.com/cburroughs/pep8.py/tree/master), or you can grab the unmodified version from [an older revision](http://github.com/cburroughs/pep8.py/blob/53031f183f83dbc4f2890c999aac2fe2cab75ab3/pep8.py)

[PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) is another option, although I haven't use it

Comment: wow, kudos for the time taken for the explanation

Answer (score 12):

[pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) and [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) would be a good start.

pylint in particular is very configurable, and you can enforce quite a few things with it.

Comment: Great, seems exactly what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Link to pyflakes is broken

Answer (score 4):

Found this stackoverflow question while searching for a pep8 style enforcement tool when taking over an existing (legacy) project.

https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8

```
autopep8 -i yourpythonsourcefile.py
```

will automagically convert all the source code to confirm with pep8. Tried it on my legacy project and it works great.  So I thought I would update this answer here in SO.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a script called `reindent.py` thats sometimes included in your system's python distribution which will go through and re-indent all your code to the recommended 4 spaces indenting.

Heres a copy of it in case you can't find it in your distribution: http://www.koders.com/python/fid24D30FCD2CE388C67CB980EF55630D25970CFB96.aspx?s=cdef%3Aparser

Comment: Thanks, although it just checks one thing, it will come in handy.